# Como abrir uma actitivity a partir de um fragment em java

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Como abrir uma activity após clicar em um Listview que está no Fragment, eu estou usando:

```
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NovaActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(listener);

    }
```

mas a aplicação para após clicar. Por favor se alguém souber como resolver isso eu agradeço.

LogCat:

```
07-01 16:06:32.979: V/21st Polling:(408): clicked
07-01 16:06:36.489: V/21st Polling:(408): clicked
07-01 16:06:39.789: D/AndroidRuntime(408): Shutting down VM
07-01 16:06:39.789: W/dalvikvm(408): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.appsherlok/com.example.appsherlok.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3348)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3288)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:126)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1036)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1180)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3330)
07-01 16:06:39.849: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  ... 12 more
```

Amigos, um detalhe! o app tem 3 tabs, esse listview está no primeiro. 
Quando eu abro o app apresenta a lista, clico, e funciona direito. 
Mas quando eu vou para outra tab e volto para a lista, clico e acontece o erro.

Comment: A princípio não deveria gerar nenhum erro com esse código, poderia incluir o log de erro?

Comment: O jeito que o Cícero mencionou em sua resposta é ineficiente e consome muita memória. Se você tiver uma ListView com 10 mil itens, cada um deles terá a implementação de um Listener. Imagine a lentidão no scroll. Sugiro que você edite a pergunta com o Stacktrace do Logcat, pois a príncipio seu código está correto.

Comment: Concordo com o @Wakim, não deveria dar erro esse trecho de código. Acho que o erro é no onPause de Activity do Fragment.

Comment: @MarceloFilho você poder ser mais específico?

Comment: Quando você está iniciando a nova activity, a atual (pai do fragmento) está passando pelo onPause. Vê se o Null não é nesse momento.

Comment: amigo @MarceloFilho eu sou novato em java, tu pode me mostrar como verificar e como usar?

Comment: @EmersonBarcellos, seu app tem uma activity que por sua vez tem um fragmento, que por sua vez tem um listview correto? Nessa sua activity voce esta sobreescrevendo o metodo onPause? Se sim veja se dentro dele nao ha algum problema com o codigo dentro. Caso nao, pode dar mais detalhes de como esta implementando seu app.

Comment: @MarceloFilho tu percebeu que eu adicionei mais dados à minha pergunta? de onde/como acontece o erro?

Comment: Cara, pela stack ta dando erro no onPause da sherlok... Da sempre essa mesma stack? Essa sherlock é da action bar?

Comment: @MarceloFilho eu acho que o problema estava na estrutura talvez no Adapter do tab. eu troque [para essa](https://github.com/vgrec/SherlockActionBarTabs) e não apresentou mais erro. Muito obrigado cara!

Comment: Emerson, não quer postar sua solução, com detalhes, em forma de resposta mais abaixo? Isso pode ajudar outras pessoas que venham a ter um problema semelhante.

Answer (score 1):

Se seu `ListView` tiver um adapter, coloque o evento na view customizada (row).

Mas exemplificando sua situação...

Faça a criação do evento dentro do `OnCreateView()` mesmo.

Considere a implementação dessa função:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {



}
```